# Why isn't a class's __new__ method in its __dict__?

Tags: python

Brief context: I'm attempting to edit a class's default arguments to its `__new__` method. I need access to the method, and I was attempting to get access in the same way I accessed its other methods - through its `__dict__`.

But here, we can see that its `__new__` method isn't in its `__dict__`.

Is this related to `__new__` being a Static Method? If so, why aren't those in a class's `__dict__`? Where are they stored in the object model?

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, a):
        print(a)
        return object.__new__(cls)
    def f(a):
        print(a)
   ....:         

In [12]: A.__dict__['f']
Out[12]: <function __main__.A.f>

In [13]: A.__dict__['__new__']
Out[13]: <staticmethod at 0x103a6a128>

In [14]: A.__new__
Out[14]: <function __main__.A.__new__>

In [16]: A.__dict__['__new__'] == A.__new__
Out[16]: False

In [17]: A.__dict__['f'] == A.f
Out[17]: True
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Why do you think `A.__dict__['__new__']` is `object.__new__`?

Comment: Good point. I have edited the question. 
The overall question remains: I've also added a couple of lines of code that show that its `__new__` is handled differently to its `f` method

Comment: This is Python 3, correct?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The question here is about the `__dict__` attribute of the class object, not of an instance of the class.

Comment: `A.__dict__` has `__new__` as an entry, but it's not the same object as `A.__new__`; the question is why that is the case, whereas `A.__dict__['f']` *is* the same object as `A.f`.

Comment: Sure, but that has nothing to do with the difference between `__new__` and `f` in the question.

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 2):

`A.__dict__['new']` is the staticmethod descriptor, where as `A.__new__` is the actual underlying function.

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods

if you need to call the function, or get it by using a string (at runtime), use `getattr(A, '__new__')`

```
>>> A.__new__
<function A.__new__ at 0x02E69618>
>>> getattr(A, '__new__')
<function A.__new__ at 0x02E69618>
```

Python 3.5.1

```py
class A(object):
def __new__(cls, a):
    print(a)
    return object.__new__(cls)
def f(a):
    print(a)

>>> A.__dict__['__new__']
<staticmethod object at 0x02E66B70>
>>> A.__new__
<function A.__new__ at 0x02E69618>
>>> object.__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x64EC98E8>
>>> A.__new__(A, 'hello')
hello
<__main__.A object at 0x02E73BF0>
>>> A.__dict__['__new__'](A, 'hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
>>> getattr(A, '__new__')
<function A.__new__ at 0x02E69618>
```